# goslate: too many requests

Tags: python

Когда я пытаюсь совершить перевод через goslate у меня почти всегда вылетает ошибка too many requests, где-то (уже не вспомню, где) вычитал, что это происходит, если ваш IP внесен в ЧС Google. На сколько я понимаю, именно для этих целей в goslate есть поддержка proxy, но вот проблема: сколько я не смотрел, везде для используют urllib2, и как это на "трёшке" реализовать я не понимаю. Пробовал искать способы подключения прокси для urllib3, но и это не работает*1. Пробовал просто заменить import urllib2 на import urllib.request as urllib2, но и тут выводит `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'ProxyHandler' and 'int'`

*1

```
import urllib.request as urllib
prox={"http": "http://172.67.182.138:80"}
opener = urllib.FancyURLopener(prox)
gs = goslate.Goslate(opener=opener)
gs.translate("сантехник", 'en')
```

(ошибка: TypeError: open() got an unexpected keyword argument 'timeout')

Comment: goslate 1.5.1 Released: Jan 4, 2016 вы уверены, что оно до сих пор должно работать? ;)

Comment: Спасибо. пойду искать другую библиотеку.